# Enterprise level SaaS - Relevant frameworks and methodology

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, saas

I am beginning work on an individual project to bring an existing product out of the dark ages of classic ASP and into the light. My biggest decision to make before embarking on this lengthy journey is determining what frameworks and methodology I will implement for the new design.

Right now I am looking at MVC or MVVM (from what I gather this is just Silverlight?) for the web interface, Entity Framework or something I write myself as the model and MSSQL as the data.

Unfortunately I am just a fledgling programmer and I am not particularly aware of trends in the world of programming in general. I don't know what is just a passing fad and what technologies actually have lasting potential. I would really like to use something that is likely to remain relevant for some time. So I am looking to the professionals here for input on ideas that worked for you, pitfalls to watch out for and things to keep an eye on.

I appreciate any and all suggestions, keeping in mind that using the Microsoft and .Net is something of a prerequisite. I really want to make sure I am headed in the right direction before I start as this will probably take several months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for frameworks I personally suggest:

- ASP.NET MVC 3 of MVC 4, depending on the question if beta software is allowed.
- Entity Framework 4.3 or 5.0. 5.0 is a lot faster (is has auto compilation) but it's still a Release Candidate.
- AutoMapper to map between Entities and ViewModels.
- Ninject for dependency injection (useful if you want to write unit tests).
- JQuery for stuff like clientside validation (integrates perfectly with ASP.NET MVC).
- Possible some CSS framework like Bootstrap.
- Maybe RestSharp so you can easily perform requests.
- In case it's a cloud service (most SaaS are) and you'd like to host it on Azure (brilliant integration with the .NET stack) you'll need the Azure SDK.

As for software achitecture:

- Use service layers
- Use the repository patterns
- Use ViewModels to pass to your view instead of entities
- Set up a dependency injection container

That's my advice, I personally find this a golden combination for building enterprise applications (while not wasting too much time configuring lots of things).

Pitfalls:

- I don't know if unit testing is really necessary. I should definately keep it in mind while setting up the architecture, but I personally choose to do that later because I don't even know if my product will succeed, so I can better put my time in building a fast Minimal Viable Product.
- Don't assume anything. You can waste months of your precious time working on a cool feature that you think everyone will like, but often this is not the case. Do just the absolutely required minimum, and improve it later if your users like it.

Answer (score 1):

I will add more to @Leon suggestions as I see those suggestion are great from application framework perspective, while I wanted to write here from cloud methodology perspective.

As you have chosen SaaS, definitely you are moving completely in Cloud while bring your application and data to cloud all together, that's great!!

There are several layers to any cloud application and to understand lets see what a cloud service stack look like. If we take an example of Windows Azure:

1. You have Compute, where your application runs with a web server (or not).
2. You have Azure table store which you can use to store key value pair in a row and then access them very fast.
3. You have Azure Queue allows decoupling of different parts of a cloud application, enabling cloud applications to be easily built with different technologies and easily scale with traffic needs.
4. You have Access Control Services to authenticate users through OpenID or AD
5. You have service bus to connect other services in cloud or on-premise at 3rd party.
6. You have Azure Blob storage to use as web based flat file server
7. You have Azure Cache (an in-memory cache build to scale in cloud)
8. You have SQL Azure as you cloud database
9. There are many more services which you can explorer and use

So when you decide to move your application from traditional web hosting to cloud you really have to look about how to take advantage of these different cloud services to scale your application when needed and save you lots of money.

With you application in Cloud you try something as below:

1. Keep you application logic as small as possible
2. Keep your static content outside the compute
3. Use cloud based cache for fast access as application scale out
4. Move data out of traditional RDBMS databases to NoSQL Framework (key-value pair, document etc to save money and flexibility), if possible and applicable
5. Take advantage of other available services to reduce application complexity

If you consider above aspect in your mind you will create a true cloud based application which will be fast and will save you money.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions! Unfortunately cloud based services arent really an option at this point :(